# Monitoring and statistics through libvirt

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Is it possible to monitor and gather statistics in realtime (CPU,
memory, HDD, network, ... - something like dstat) of guest systems
with libvirt through console from host system (KVM based)? If yes, do
those guests need to be created through libvirt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

virt-manager has some of this built in, but if you want more detail, look at [nagios-virt](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/nagios-virt/).  Alternatively, you can monitor it by installing the same tools (nagios, ZenOSS, etc) on the guest that you'd use on a non-vm system.

Answer (score 5):

virt-top?

http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-top/

Answer (score 0):

I run munin on my virtual clients to gather this kind of information.  Information is gathered every 5 minutes and available in graphical format via rrd.  Data is available via http from my munin server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collectd with libvirt plugin
https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3alibvirt